# Can I use func_num_args as stand-alone counter

Tags: php, parameters, functional-programming, arguments

So the [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) is useful inside a function, if you pass a dynamic number of arguments. I red the documentation, but I was wondering if there is another use of it.

What if I want to use it as a stand-alone function, outside a function, like this, so I can get a number.

```
echo func_num_args(fopen());
```

`fopen` is just an example, I could replace it with any other standard or custom-made function with a standard number of arguments.

I tried it and I get `fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given` and `func_num_args(): Called from the global scope - no function context`. 
If this worked, it could be useful when debugging another programmer's code, s/he spread the code to multiple files and there are tons of LOCs.

Does `func_num_args` works this way or I have to use something else ? Thanks

Comment: What? Can't work out what you're actually asking. Are you saying "can func_get_args tell me the number of args a function expects"? If so, no, and I can see no use case for it to do so.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to find out how many arguments `fopen` takes? That's not how that works. You'd need to use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) for that.

Comment: The documentation clearly says that it "Returns the number of arguments _passed_ to the function". So it seems trivially obvious that, no, you can't. Did you _try_ to do it and see what happens? As mentioned, you probably could use reflection to achieve what you want. Or...just read the documentation for the relevant function

Comment: @JonStirling Yes that is what I am asking. Check my edits in the OP for a use case for it

Comment: @iainn Thanks for suggesting Reflection

Comment: Your use-case makes no sense. You'd need to put this bit of code in, when you should just look at the documentation, or drill down further. Knowing only how many args a function takes tells you nothing.

Comment: @ADyson I red the documentation and I tried it, check my edit in the OP. But I asked anyway because maybe I was doing something wrong, or there was a hack or a tip I didnt know. Custom functions from other developers dont usually have decent documentation or no documentation at all.

Comment: Ok. But then why do you need to know the number of args? On its own, that's not very useful. It's not clear what purpose this would have in a debugging exercise? You still don't know what should be passed to them, or which will be considered mandatory, or really anything much at all that will help your code. You can't verify that the calling code is passing the correct number of arguments. If a function's not documented and you don't know how to use it, you need to ask the developer concerned, or failing that, study the code.

Comment: As you tagged this q with functional programming: Functions are meant to return a computed value based on their arguments solely. So if you pass in a function invocation to `func_num_args` it gets the result value of that very computation, not the number of arguments passed in. Please note that reflection (`func_num_args` performs reflection actually) is frequently an indicator for bad code except for very specific and rare use cases.

Comment: @ADyson, for what it's worth, in JavaScript, `((x,y) => x + y).length` returns `2` to represent the function *arity* (number of parameters a particular function has) – so at least *one* popular language deemed this an essential property of functions – wrt writing code that depends on this property, that's a different discussion.

Comment: @JonStirling see my above remark

Comment: @ftor thank you adding voice of reason – this is a perfectly good question. most php programmers (if that's his/her own only fluent language) just don't understand why you'd possibly do something like that

Comment: @naomik you mention another language that will tell you the number of parameters a function has. Ok, sure, it's possible in JS, but to my mind that still doesn't demonstrate an actual useful reason for needing to discover such a value. What would you do with that information once you've got it, which would in some way be productive? Maybe I'm being a bit dense but I just don't see it, and simply stating that it can be done in another language doesn't in itself prove that it's a useful feature.

Comment: @ADyson a practical example is [higher-order functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), ie functions that are built using other functions, or functions that take another function as an argument for other use. Techniques like currying and partial application may rely on an input function's arity, to determine the computed result. These types of things are possible in PHP, but uncommon because the language does not express it well in a functional (assignment-free) style

Comment: @naomik ok that makes some sense. JS's .bind() method would be a case of partial application, I guess? The OP was talking about using it for debugging, so my mind was going down that road, but I can't really see what value it would have in that scenario. P.S. I always hated functional programming at uni. Then again, I liked Java, so my taste was probably questionable in those days :-)

Comment: @ADyson functional programming is very painful when attempted in a language that doesn't cater to a functional style – i think the couple months i spent studying [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) taught me more about computing than i had learned in the past decade (studied JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, Python, C, etc) ...

Comment: (continued) ... i think this is due to the fact the lambda calculus is just a pure model of computation – instead of getting lost in language-specific details, untyped lambda calculus has 3 syntax constructs can learn in 5 minutes, the rest of the time you're thinking about computation – the things you'll learn will make you appreciate what higher level languages give you, and maybe help you understand the cost of using some of those features – most amazing of all, you get to see how *every* possible computer program can be represented using the same 3 constructs.